# Returning non-empty row numbers using VBA

Tags: vba

[image]

I have a spreadsheet like this, and I would like to have a function that returns the list of row numbers non-empty cells in column B. In this case, it should return "2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 18, 20, 21, 22, 23, 25, 26)

How do I do this in VBA?

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?  We might be able to help you figure out why it's not working.

Comment: Is the list the end or are you going to use those rows somewhere else to get to the final output?

Answer (score 0):

```
Function GetEmptyCount()
    Dim arr(), x&, cell
    With Range("B1:B" & Cells(Rows.Count - 1, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
        For Each cell In .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Cells
            x = x + 1
            ReDim Preserve arr(1 To x)
            arr(x) = cell.Row
        Next
    End With
    GetEmptyCount = arr
End Function

Sub Test()
    Dim x, c
    x = GetEmptyCount()
    For Each c In x: MsgBox c: Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score -2):

You can check the length of the cell value something like

```
IF(Length(Cell) > 0 THEN
      // Include the row
ELSE
      // skip the row
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. You may be able to format the code even better.

Comment: Looks better now. However, two brackets open and only one closes. Downvote.